# two javascript files that hate each other

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous, easyslider, lightwindow

I have recently been working on a site and have implemented both light window and easyslider. They both work fine on their own but if you combine the two of them then either easy slider works or light window. I have come to the conclusion that they are both trying to use a function with the same name but with different declarations...

The address for the site is http://semaphoredesign.com/web-devel/oceanair/

Just fixed the missing prototype.js file

Comment: You're trying to use Prototype and jQuery on the same site. You'll need to call jQuery.noConflict() and then stop using the $ sign to reference jQuery.

Comment: ok, thanks, where would one declare jQuery.noConflict()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Prototype and jQuery together:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/easyslider/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // declare a global variable set to jQuery.noConflict();
    var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
    // in all jQuery scripts, use jq (or whatever you call the global) instead of $.
</script>
```

Comment: I did this and Easyslider works however lightwindow does not, light window does not have any declarations inside of the html doc

Comment: by doing this i have made easyslider work and lightwindow fail

Comment: do i need to change all of the $ to jq in the .js files?

Comment: you don't have to change all the "$" inside ready if you pass "$" as an argument of ready. Read "Magic Shortcuts" section here http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 2):

When i look in my console in chrome i'm seeing that you're getting a 404 on your prototype.js, which lightwindow wants. Try addressing that and see what happens.

Comment: my bad, forgot to press send on the ftp, it is there now

Comment: There you go. Now your problem is, as @interrobang suggests, a $ conflict. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/